# Run applications on the cloud

Tags: .net, web-services, web, cloud, iaas

Guys I'm wondering how can I run windows applications on the cloud through web browser like this website (https://online.cameyo.com/public).

If anyone know the general idea behind this project, which programming languages offers desktop streaming through web and all these stuff.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to search for the phrase 'desktop virtualisation software' - this type of solution can provide access to a Windows 'desktop' via a browser.

Take a look at Amazons AWS Workspaces, VMware's View or Citrix's XenDesktop for common examples.

There are several open source versions which appear to do the same type of thing but I have not seen them in use personally.